# Overlay div is not appearing on top of my main div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an overlay design, I have a button when clicked, a new overlay div will be displayed on top my main div , how ever I can't seem to figure out why the overlay div I have created is not appearing. I have watch tutorials and search similar situation like mine but I cant understand why it is not showing.

This is my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan+2|Liu+Jian+Mao+Cao&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="thiscss/randomqoutes.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>RCaT11</h2>
    <div class="qoutewrapper">
        <h1>Have an Inspirational day!</h1>
        <button id="btn">Genererate Qoute</button>
    </div>

    <div class="overlaycontainer">

    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/randomqoutes.js"></script>

    </html>
```

this is my css file, I have set the "overlaycontainer" class display to none to that it will not show up first until the button is clicked :

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(to left, #ED8F20, #EBD626);
margin: 0;
padding: 50px;
     }

 .container {
 display: flex;
  }

   .qoutewrapper {
    font-family: 'Liu Jian Mao Cao', cursive, sans-serif;
    width: 900px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
   padding: 10px;
   display: flex
   }

 .qoutewrapper h1 {
white-space: nowrap;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 70px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
left: 90px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

h2 {
font-family: 'Liu Jian Mao Cao', cursive, sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
position: absolute;
left: 90%;
color: red;
float: right;
  }

.container button {
color: rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.897) !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: none;
padding: 12px;
border: 2px dotted rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.897) !important;
font-weight: 800;
float: right;
margin-top: 200px;
}

.container button:hover {
color: #EBD626 !important;
background: rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.897);
border-color: none !important;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
display: flex;
}

.overlaycontainer {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.7;
display: none;
 }
```

this is my javascript file, I have written that when button is clicked the display will be set to "flex" to display the "overlaycontainer", however it is not showing up,

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.querySelector('.overlaycontainer').style.display = "flex";
 })
```

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position your `.overlaycontainer` by adding these CSS lines and it will show up.

```
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
```

An element must have a height and width to show up, it does not mean we always have to set width and height to elements. What was happening is, you were setting the height of the `.overlaycontainer`  to 100% and it was not taking it and for that its parent must-have fix width to work.

Normally overlay is positioned.

The `position` property is used to manipulate the location of an element.
The `position:absolute` is always refer to its parent, which needs to be set as `position:relative`.

When you change the left or top value the position of the `.overlaycontainer` changes.  if you give `position: relative` to the parent or any grandparents element of the overlay (in must of the cases you have to), it will change its location on that respect.  if any of the element's ancestors has no `position: relative` which is our case, the element will be relative to the body.

Comment: it did work thank you for helping. Can I ask why does setting the position to absolute and top and left to 0 did display the div? I need to have a clear view whats going on this. thank you